# T-SQL 2008 Select first second and third row of group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a derived table that has achievements in one column, personID in the next Column, and a Achievement Level In the next column.
My goal is to create a table that has distinct achievements in the farthest left column, and the next five columns are the number of people that have that Achievement as their highest ranking one, second highest ranking, third highest ranking etc. achievement.
Thus A Person with rank 2 as their highest ranking achievement, and 12 as their second highest ranked achievement, would be counted in the first column
for Achiev2, And the second column for Achiev12

Ranks range from 1 to Infinity. 
A rank of 1 is the highest rank.

Example Source Table

```
Achievement | PersonID | Rank
------------------------------
Achiev1     |     1    |   1
Achiev2     |     3    |   2
AChiev2     |     1    |   2
Achiev1     |     2    |   1
```

Expected Output

```
Achievement | #OfPeopleHighestAchiev | #OfPeopleSecondHighestAchiev | etc.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Achiev1     |           2            |              0
Achiev2     |           1            |              1
```

I'm unsure how to do this and any direction of where to start would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Based on the data and the logic described, I would expect the rows to be:  "1, 1" and "0, 2".

Comment: In this care Person 1 and Person 2 have Achiev1 as their highest ranking achievement. There is not a person with achieve 1 as their second highest ranking achievement because it is the highest ranked achievement. Person 3 has Achiev2 as their highest ranking achievement and person 1 has Achieve 2 as their second highest ranked achievement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one of possible variants:

```
select
    Achievement,
    sum(case when RankNum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as HighRank1,
    sum(case when RankNum = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as HighRank2,
    ...
from (
    select
        PersonId,
        Achievement,
        row_number() over(
            partition by PersonId order by Rank) as RankNum
    from sourcetable
) as t
group by Achievement
```

the main idea is to assign number to each achievement for each person, this is done by over(partition..

check fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8f0f/8

Comment: You may want to add an explanation of what is going on.  Just providing a drop-in solution is not necessarily helpful to the learning process.

Comment: @dubstylee I suppose this particular code is self-explanatory and any comments are useless, otherway I need to copy-paste ansi sql standard here

Comment: This would work well if the first column always had rank 1 in it, but here lies the problem I can't get over. And that is the first column will be the highest rank that person has achieved. not a set number. (EG. achievement 1 always has rank 1 achievement 2 always has rank 2, column one is the sum of people that have that achievement as their highest ranking achievement

Comment: @ChadJPetersen, how do you know what the person's second highest achievement is then, if the achievement # is always = to the rank #.  Seems like more of a database design issue than a query issue.

Comment: Exactly, this is the part that has me stumped. I could use this derived table in a CTE and  group it by personID then if I select max rank I could join it back in to get the first, But I am unsure how to get the next four ranks.

Comment: @ChadJPetersen looks like I've got what you need, check updated answer

Comment: The row_number() OVER(Partition... was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use conditional aggegation:

```
select achievement,
       sum(case when rank = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as rank1,
       sum(case when rank = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as rank2,
       sum(case when rank = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as rank3,
       sum(case when rank = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as rank4,
       sum(case when rank = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as rank5
from source
group by achievement;
```

Note:  this seems to satisfy the intent of the question.  The sample results, however, seem to be following a logic different from what is described.